# How to access controls that are inside a TabControl tab?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

This is all I have so far.

```
tabControl1.TabPages[0].???
```

I have a PictureBox inside of TabPage1 of my TabControl.

**How can I change the image location with code and not the properties pane?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the controls appear inside a container (as a TabControl), they're all defined on the form, so there is no need to access them through the container.

Instead of:

```
tablControl1.TabPages[0].MyContainedControl...
```

Simply type:

```
MyContainedControl...
```

Answer (score 7):

Unless you've set [GenerateMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630.aspx) to false on the picture box or you're building the form dynamically you should be able to reference the picture box by its name:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "...";
```

Otherwise, assuming the picture box is the first control in the first tab page you can use the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) collection:

```
var picBox = (PictureBox) tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls[0];
picBox.ImageLocation = "...";
```

If you know there is exactly one picture box somewhere but you're not sure what page it's on or where on that page it is you can use Linq:

```
var picBox = tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<Control>()
    .SelectMany(page => page.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    .First();
picBox.ImageLocation = "...";
```