# get textbox that is in the selected tab

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol with numerous tabs that all contain a textbox.  How can I select the textbox that is in the currently selected tab?

I have this which captures the tabchanged event and tells me which tab is selected, but I cannot figure out how to find the textbox that is in the tab and do

```
textbox.Select(0, 0);
```

to select certain text in this textbox...

```
private void onTabChange(Object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: What's the presentation system is being used?

Answer (score 1):

This *really* sounds like a design mistake.  High odds that this TextBox should not be on a tab page at all.  If you want to have *one* text box to be present on *every* tab page then that's possible, Winforms makes it easy to move controls:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox1.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    }
```

If you *really* meant for any text box to be picked, like the first one in the tab order then:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var box = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Reverse().FirstOrDefault();
        if (box != null) {
            // etc...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following links can provide you some hints about your problem
[How to access controls that are inside a TabControl tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297442/how-to-access-controls-that-are-inside-a-tabcontrol-tab)
and
[How to get control(s) from TabPage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351462/how-to-get-controls-from-tabpage-in-c)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for answering a first question. Please consider adding the main takeaways from the links to your answer, as over time, the links tend to disappear - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
Tab TabView = (Tab)sender;
TextView txt_Tab = (TextView)TabView.FindControl("TextBoxName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextBox myTB = tabControl2.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as TextBox;
myTB.Select(0, 0);
```